# Последовательные запросы cUrl

Tags: php, curl

Как можно отправлять новый запрос, после ответа сервера на предидущий? Т.к. для последующих запросов параметры состоят из ответов предидущих.

```html
<?php
/**
* http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php
*/
/**
* Send a GET request using cURL
* @param string $url to request
* @param array $get values to send
* @param array $options for cURL
* @return string
*/

function curl_get($url, array $get = NULL, array $options = array()) {
    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url . (strpos($url, "?") === FALSE ? "?" : "") . http_build_query($get) ,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0, //unsafe, but the fastest solution for the error " SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK"
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0, //unsafe, but the fastest solution for the error " SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK"
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);


    if (!$result = curl_exec($ch)) {
        trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}


$url = "https://iiko.biz:9900/api/0/auth/access_token";
$data = [
 "user_id" => "demoDelivery",
 "user_secret"=> "PI1yFaKFCGvvJKi"
];

//Запрос на токен который мне нужно использовать в следующем запросе
$access_token = curl_get($url, $data);

//Запрос на данные организации
$getOrganizationInfo = curl_get("https://iiko.biz:9900/api/0//organization/list", ["access_token" => $access_token]);
$getOrganizationInfo = json_decode($getOrganizationInfo);

//Получить id организации
$getId = $getOrganizationInfo[0]->id;  

//Получить меню
$getMenu = curl_get("https://iiko.biz:9900/api/0/nomenclature/" . $getId . "?access_token=" . $access_token);

//Данные пользователя
$name = "Иван";
$phone = "71235678901";
$deliveryType = "Доставка";
$city = "Москва";
$street = "Красная площадь";
$building = "1";
$korpus = "";
$room = "14";
$comment = "comment";
```

Всё ломаете на первом шаге, т.к. не получив `$access_token` запускаю след. функцию в которой его использую...Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В представленном вами примере curl-запрос возвращает access_token c двойными кавычками в начале и конце:

```
string(89) ""enAr4qJE8rjK1pEmqNs8MRW0pcZKper1FLfYec9FPN5n2jpelnUBedO51IlJTy6IiMH74Nm_v5rjRVV0T9AvEQ2""
```

При попытке передать такой токен в следующие методы, api возвращает ошибку, ссылаясь на неверный токен.

Для решения проблемы вам необходимо убрать лишние кавычки.

```
$access_token = curl_get($url, $data);
var_dump($access_token); //string(89) ""enAr4qJE8rjK1pEmqNs8MRW0pcZKper1FLfYec9FPN5n2jpelnUBedO51IlJTy6IiMH74Nm_v5rjRVV0T9AvEQ2""
$token = trim($access_token,'"'); //string(87) "enAr4qJE8rjK1pEmqNs8MRW0pcZKper1FLfYec9FPN5n2jpelnUBedO51IlJTy6IiMH74Nm_v5rjRVV0T9AvEQ2"
```

Соответственно, далее уже передавать исправленный токен $token